# XmlSerializer for WCF client

Tags: c#, performance, wcf

I need help with WCF service performance.

Given:

1) Class library which includes WCF service reference (generated automatically service contracts and client) - MyLibrary.dll

2) External program which calls client from MyLibrary.dll

Problem: first call to wcf client is very slow

I assume the reason for that is the fact that serialization code for my service contract is generated at runtime.

There is a solution for that described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/startup-time-of-wcf-client-applications-using-the-xmlserializer

According to this solution I should:

1) Add XmlSerializerFormatAttribute to my service contract

2) Generate MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll.cs with command:

```
svcutil.exe /t:xmlSerializer  <MyLibraryPath>
```

3) Compile generated file to separate assembly MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll with command:

```
csc /r:MyLibrary.dll out:MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll /t:library MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll.cs
```

4) Make sure that generated assembly is in the same directory as my external program binaries.

I have done all of that and MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll is still being generated at runtime.

What am I missing? Thanks for help.